How to set up a URL rewrite for Sitefinity Cloud?
I've just launched a very large site. We have a number of assets on our old site that we need to point to.
All of the assets are one of these formats:
asset12345.aspx
assetfactory=1234.aspx
Assets/sub-dir/sub-dir/file_name.pdf (or some other file type)
We have moved the entire old site to a ww2. We are trying to point our new site assets to our old site assets.
Example:
www.sitename.com/asset12345.aspx points to ww2.sitename.com/asset12345.aspx
These are the rewrites I've tried, but haven't been successful:
Attempt 1:
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect .gov/asset to ww2" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^.*\.gov/asset.*$" ignoreCase="true" />
      <action type="Redirect" url=https://ww2.sitename.gov/{R:0} appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>

Attempt 2:
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite Asset URLs" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^asset(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.sitename\.gov$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url=https://ww2.sitename.gov/{R:1} redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>

Neither one has worked and I'm getting desperate. Any thoughts?

In Attempt 1 you need to have a group, e.g. something in brackets and the string that matches the first group, will go where {R:1} is. If you have multiple groups, then you can use {R:2}, etc.
In Attempt 2 can you try the following:

remove the escape slash here:
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.sitename.gov$" />
make sure to add quotes in the url here:   <action type="Redirect" url="https://ww2.sitename.gov/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />

